# ASP.NET Core View Injection problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, autofac

Has anyone tried to use the new View Injection from ASP.NET Core?
I'm trying to use straight forward as described on the documentation (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/dependency-injection.html) but no success at all.

The unique diference from my implementation and the documentation is that I'm using AutoFac for DI.
When I try to use the injection on my view I get an exception that my Service has not been registered.

```
@inject Domain.Service.LevelService LevelService
```

Error Message:

ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'Domain.Service.LevelService' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

Btw, the service is correctly registered and can be accessed from the controller for example.

**Edit to include Startup:**

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.            
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession();
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    return new AutofacServiceProvider(DependencyInjection.RegisterServices(services));
}
```

Code of the method RegisterServices:

```
public static IContainer RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Create the container builder.
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();           

    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ServiceInjectionModule)))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x =>
                    {
                        var t = (ServiceInjectionModule)Activator.CreateInstance(x, new object[] { true });
                        t.AddtoContainer(builder);      
                    });

    // Add automapper configurations            
    var mapperConfiguration = AutoMapperConfig.Configure(); 
    var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
    builder.RegisterInstance(mapper).As<IMapper>();

    // Populate default services
    builder.Populate(services);

    return builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: have you looked at these docs?  http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html

Comment: @ScottSelby, yes, unfortunately that only explains on how to use that as ASP.NET Core default DI, not on how to use that over the views. That part as you've mentioned with the link is working very fine, all the injections are up and running, the unique problem is when I try to inject inside a View

Comment: this is a solution for your exact problem , you need to create a custom base view class and implement that one , then you use the `@inject ... `    http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html?highlight=view#enable-property-injection-for-view-pages

Comment: @ScottSelby, what you've sent me is for MVC5, not ASP.NET Core MVC. I already take a read at that before creating this question, unfortunately that is quite different. Another point is that I'm trying to use Service Injection, not property injection

Comment: can you post the DI configuration from the startup class?

Comment: @MateoVelenik just updated the code

Comment: The MVC documentation page is for ASP.NET classic, not Core. The only DI available for ASP.NET Core is via the Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection package. All the actual hooks - controller injection, view injection, whatever - are now owned by ASP.NET Core. I'll update the docs to be more clear.

Comment: @TravisIllig, I know that and I'm using the correct package and setup, the controller injections are working pretty great, my problem is only when trying to call the services on the view. I read your updated docs and nothing changed on my side, the implementation is exactly how I did on my side. You guys were able to use view injections without problems?

Comment: I only mentioned it because you linked first thing in your question to docs that don't apply to your situation. We didn't test every hook in the ASP.NET Core framework because we didn't write it - if it's not working, it's not because of Autofac.

Comment: Well, my link was to MS official documentation, the link pointing back to the wrong place inside Autofac docs came from the comments. I know that it wasn't written by you, I only asked if someone there already had a proof of concept, or something running that uses View Injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem.
Well, I didn't paid attention and seems that no one too :p.

The problem is that I'm trying to inject an instance and not an interface. Just changed the implementation and everything started working.

Final code:

`@inject Domain.Service.Interfaces.ILevelService LevelService`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the assembly scanning section you've written. It's much easier to use the built in functionality of AutoFac. Not sure your code is .Net Core just based on the fact you're not using `GetTypeInfo`. GetTypeInfo is backwards compatible so will work with .Net 4.x

```
public static IContainer RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Create the container builder.
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();           

    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
           .Where(t => t.GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(typeof(ServiceInjectionModule)))
           .AsSelf();

    // Add automapper configurations            
    var mapperConfiguration = AutoMapperConfig.Configure(); 
    var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
    builder.RegisterInstance(mapper).As<IMapper>();

    // Populate default services
    builder.Populate(services);

    return builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: Even with GetTypeInfo I'm not being able to get the views recognizing the services, still getting the `ComponentNotRegisteredException`. Were you able to use View Injection with success?

Comment: Yes, apart from your code not being .net core. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` is not supported in .net core. I used `typeof(ServiceInjectionModule).Assembly` in its place. The fact that you're injecting an instance is irrelevant, as it's completely valid to inject as instances, interfaces, named instance, delegate/factory, etc. As long as you resolve it by the same method as you registered as.